# Understand Cascading in CSS

Tags: css

Hy,

I am new to CSS and trying to understand it. In the code below, how is the style interpreted/ read to understand it. Whether the style def would apply to list and ul elements under a div that uses the class "p220mid" or what how this works. Could you guys give sample.

```
.p220mid ul li
{
    background:transparent URL('images/bline.gif') repeat-x bottom;
    width:205px;
    height:28px;
    margin-left:4px;
    padding-left:4px;
    color:4c76a0;
}
```

Thanks,
Appu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there will target all the li elements in a ul inside all elements with a class of p220mid.

If you want to target all ul and all li elements in your div you want `.p220mid ul, .p220mid ul li`

Comment: so u mean the code which i have provided will only style li elements which are inside a ul element but not all ul elements themselves. In order to target all ul elements as well I need to add .p220mid ul. Is that a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

The selector says "style all li elements that are descendants of all ul elements that are themselves descendants of all elements classed as .p220mid".

Answer (score 1):

Because you have spaces defined between your style elements (.p220mid ul li) this means that any <li> descendant elements (i.e. nested beneath the class="p220mid" and a <ul> element, whether a direct child or a grandchild or grand-grandchild) it will have the style applied.

You should read up on [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to have a better grasp of the syntax here

To clarify this example will apply the style

```html
<div class="p220mid">
    <ul>
       <li>
         class style will be applied here
       <li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and so will this example

```
<div class="p220mid">
    <div>
        <ul>
           <li>
                class style will also be applied here
           <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited to add the example that @Anand used and another one for further clarification

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
 .p220mid ul li { 
            background:transparent URL('images/bline.gif') repeat-x bottom; 
            width:205px; 
            height:28px; 
            margin-left:4px;
            padding-left:4px; 
            color:4c76a0; 
     }
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="p220mid ">
     <ul>
       <li>
         class style will be apply here
       <li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my link http://jsfiddle.net/YyqYN/ (I have changed the background image url so that you can see more clearly)

It basically means that the style will only apply to the set of html that appears in `.p220mid ul li`.